# Snowflake on Heroku Via ODBC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Update - I got it working by using Sequel and Ruby-ODBC gems and a different build pack for Heroku (https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/daasity/heroku-buildpack-snowflake-odbc)

Had to amend the AptFile line

```
https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/odbc/linux/2.18.3/snowflake-odbc-2.18.3.x86_64.deb
```

to

```
https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/odbc/linux/latest/snowflake-odbc-2.21.0.x86_64.deb
```

I am looking for some advice to help resolve an issue I am having trying connect a Rails 5.1 app to a Snowflake database via ODBC on Heroku.
I have tried various methods but keep hitting different issues.

Steps taken so far:

- Added heroku-community/apt buildpack
- Created AptFile with the below packages:

unixodbc

unixodbc-dev

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carwow/heroku-buildpack-snowflake-odbc/master/snowflake-odbc.deb

- Added odbc_adapter gem (https://github.com/localytics/odbc_adapter)
- Modified my database.yml file to include :snowflake connection details.
- Created a new class to mirror a table held in Snowflake, added a line to  establish_connection to snowflake and a method to test the connection.

When I run this locally, everything works perfectly. When I deploy to Heroku and try to run the same method I get this error:

> ODBC::Error: S1000 (-1) [unixODBC][DSI] The error message SFRestRequestFailed could not be found in the en-US locale. Check that /app/.apt/usr/lib/snowflake/odbc/lib/SFMessages_en-US.xml exists.

When I check the file structure on Heroku, I can see that SFMessages_en_US.xml is in a different path.

I tried using isql -v to see if I could get more details but that returns an error:

> [28000][unixODBC][DSI] The error message DSIReqSettingNotFound could not be found in the en-US locale. Check that /app/.apt/usr/lib/snowflake/odbc/lib/ODBCMessages_en-US.xml exists.

I've been trying to get this to work but without being able to see the underlying error I am stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, will bear in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following (copied from Dockerfile, so you need to change that to match Heroku) before installing SNFLK ODBC drivers:

```
ENV LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
RUN apt-get install locales && locale-gen
```